# React Antd: How to remove spacing between vertical divider and any content right next to it?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, antd

```
</div>
<Divider type="vertical" style={{ width: "5px", height: "auto" , marginRight : '0px'  , padding : '0 0'}} />
<div style={{ padding : '0 0' , marginRight : '0px'}}>
```

This is what I have tried and couldn't seem to remove the space between the divider and stepper(Antd element).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Set padding:0px to div#container

Antd Steps by default has a div with id=container and padding=24px

[image]

The extra space you see is due to that div-padding.

You can remove it by defining the following code in styles.css and importing the styles in the component.

> styles.css

```
div#container {
  padding-left: 0px !important;
}
```

Check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-steps-padding-override-ce54st?file=/demo.js) for more understanding